# Linux from scratch Segmentation fault error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, segmentation-fault, linux-from-scratch

I am on [Section 6.7](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter06/linux-headers.html) trying to install the linux API headers.

I cd into the folder `/sources/linux-4.12` in my chroot environment. However when I try to run the `make mrproper` command, I get the error: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. I redid everything from [section 6.2](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/development/chapter06/kernfs.html) again, however I still get the same error.

I dont even see [this](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-from-scratch-13/chapter-6-7-lfs-version-7-7-segmentation-fault-on-make-mrproper-4175548991/) when trying to troubleshoot.

Comment: You did something wrong. Start from scratch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution to my answer was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42775415/building-lfs-segmentation-fault-with-make-on-a-graphical-shell). Still do not know why.

It was replacing 
`mount -vt devpts devpts $LFS/dev/pts -o gid=5,mode=620`  <-- (Book, does not work) to `mount -v --bind /dev/pts $LFS/dev/pts -o gid=5,mode=620`